# Lighttpd on Cygwin has different PATH variable from Cygwin shell

Tags: bash, cygwin, lighttpd

I'm running Lighttpd on Cygwin. I have a Lua CGI script that calls a BASH script which calls notepad.exe. My actual problem is running a C# application but I've tried to simplify the problem with notepad for now.

When I call the CGI web page, I get the error: notepad.exe: command not found 
But when I run the BASH from the Cygwin shell, notepad runs fine with no error.

It looks like the Path is being cleaned when lighttpd is running. How do I make sure the environment is the same?

CGI (LUA):

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

cmd = "/opt/abc/scripts/test.sh"
local f = io.popen( cmd.." ; echo RC=$?" )
assert(f)  
local str = f:read'*a'
f:close()

print ("Content-type: Text/html\n")
print ("<br><b>Output</b>: ", str)
print ("</body></html>")
```

BASH:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Test.sh" 
echo "<br>PATH<br> $PATH<hr>"

notepad.exe 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lighttpd was being started by windows task scheduler on system startup and didn't need a user to be logged in. This meant that the server was being started in windows 'Session 0' which is marked as non-interactive. [More info on Windows Sessions](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/services/understanding-windows-service-hardening)

My solution was to throw a simple batch file into the startup folder that would start lighttpd. Alternatively I could have created a cygwin service that automatically starts and ensure that the interact with desktop option is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try invoking with `bash -l`?
also - whats wrong with setting the path in your script?

(don't have a cygwin machine handy to test)

Comment: This doesn't help. I manually added the path and notepad isn't 'displayed'. It shows in the task manager but the GUI window doesn't show up.

Comment: @tuxGurl  Is lighttpd running as a service or as plain-vanilla app in a window?  If its a service - did you enable the ability to interact with the desktop?